# Group the similar boxes

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a set of (X,Y) coordinates which split a unit square into sub-rectangles. Suppose my coordinates are -

```
         (    x1,    y1)    (    x2,    y2)      

         (0.0000,0.0000)    (0.3412,0.4175)   
         (0.7445,0.0000)    (1.0000,0.6553)   
         (0.7445,0.6553)    (1.0000,1.0000)   
         (0.0000,0.6553)    (0.7445,1.0000)   
         (0.3412,0.0000)    (0.7445,0.4175)   
         (0.3412,0.4175)    (0.7445,0.6553)   
         (0.0000,0.4175)    (0.3412,0.6553)....etc (total 10,000 coordinates)
```

As an example I took only 16 set of data and these coordinates splits my square like this-

[image]

**Definition of similar box**

Those boxes who has the similar number of neighbors are consider as the *similar box*. For the image above the the **box[8], box[13]** etc has **4** nearest neighbor. So they are considered as similar boxes.

The image below should make this clear-

[image]

**::MY PROBLEM::**

From the image we can see-

*For **box[8]** the nearest boxes are:*

**box(1) (which has 4 neighbors)**

**box[4] (which also has 4 neighbors)**

**box[14] (has 4 neighbors)**

**box[16] (has 4 neighbors)**

So in this case the sum of the neighbors of nearest boxes = 4+4+4+4 =16

Again *for **box[13]** the nearest boxes are:*

**box[3] (which has 6 neighbors)**

**box[5] (which also has 4 neighbors)**

**box[6] (has 3 neighbors)**

**box[12] (has 3 neighbors)**

So in this case the sum of the neighbors of nearest boxes = 6+4+3+3 =16

And here the total of neighbors for (similar boxes) box[8] and box[13] = 16+16 =32.

Similarly I want to group all the boxes which have 4 neighbors and find the sum of the neighbors of their nearest boxes. And continue for each similar groups.

**My Code**

Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Rect {
public:
double x1, x2, y1, y2; // coordinates

Rect(double X1, double Y1, double X2, double Y2) {
  if (X1 < X2) {
    x1 = X1; x2 = X2;
  } else {
    x2 = X1; x1 = X2;
  }
  if (Y1 < Y2) {
    y1 = Y1; y2 = Y2;
  } else {
    y2 = Y1; y1 = Y2;
  }


}

bool isAdjacent(Rect rect) {
    if (x1 == rect.x1 || x1 == rect.x2 ||
        x2 == rect.x1 || x2 == rect.x2) {
      // use only < when comparing y1 and rect.y2 avoids sharing only a corner
      if (y1 >= rect.y1 && y1 < rect.y2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (y2 > rect.y1 && y2 <= rect.y2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect.y1 >= y1 && rect.y1 < y2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect.y2 > y1 && rect.y2 <= y2) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    if (y1 == rect.y1 || y1 == rect.y2 ||
        y2 == rect.y1 || y2 == rect.y2) {
      if (x1 >= rect.x1 && x1 < rect.x2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (x2 > rect.x1 && x2 <= rect.x2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect.x1 >= x1 && rect.x1 < x2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect.x2 > x1 && rect.x2 <= x2) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

};



void isNearest(int b){

vector<Rect> rects;     
                //Rect(  x1 ,  y1  ,   x2  ,  y2   ) 
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.0000,0.0000, 0.8147,0.1355));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.8147,0.0000, 1.0000,0.1355));

  rects.push_back(Rect(0.8147,0.1355, 0.9058,0.8350));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.0000,0.1355, 0.1270,0.9689));

  rects.push_back(Rect(0.9058,0.1355, 0.9134,0.2210));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.9058,0.8350, 1.0000,1.0000));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.8147,0.8350, 0.9058,1.0000));


  rects.push_back(Rect(0.1270,0.1355, 0.6324,0.3082));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.1270,0.9689, 0.8147,1.0000));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.0000,0.9689, 0.1270,1.0000));

  rects.push_back(Rect(0.9134,0.1355, 1.0000,0.2210));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.9134,0.2210, 1.0000,0.8350));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.9058,0.2210, 0.9134,0.8350));


  rects.push_back(Rect(0.6324,0.1355, 0.8147,0.3082));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.6324,0.3082, 0.8147,0.9689));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.1270,0.3082, 0.6324,0.9689));


  int nearBox_count = 0;

  double TotalArea=0;


  for (int x = 0; x < rects.size(); ++x) {

    if (rects[b].isAdjacent(rects[x])) {


      if (x==b) {
continue; //this is our box , so do not count it.
}


nearBox_count++;

printf("box[%d] is nearest to box[%d]  \n", (b+1), (x+1));

}
}

printf("Total number of nearest box for [%d] is %d  \n",(b+1),nearBox_count );
printf("\n");

}


int main() {

  for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
  {
    isNearest(i);
  }

return 0;
}
```

It gives the correct result like this-

```
box[1] is nearest to box[2]  
box[1] is nearest to box[4]  
box[1] is nearest to box[8]  
box[1] is nearest to box[14]  
Total number of nearest box for [1] is 4  

box[2] is nearest to box[1]  
box[2] is nearest to box[3]  
box[2] is nearest to box[5]  
box[2] is nearest to box[11]  
Total number of nearest box for [2] is 4  

box[3] is nearest to box[2]  
box[3] is nearest to box[5]  
box[3] is nearest to box[7]  
box[3] is nearest to box[13]  
box[3] is nearest to box[14]  
box[3] is nearest to box[15]  
Total number of nearest box for [3] is 6  

box[4] is nearest to box[1]  
box[4] is nearest to box[8]  
box[4] is nearest to box[10]  
box[4] is nearest to box[16]  
Total number of nearest box for [4] is 4  

box[5] is nearest to box[2]  
box[5] is nearest to box[3]  
box[5] is nearest to box[11]  
box[5] is nearest to box[13]  
Total number of nearest box for [5] is 4  

box[6] is nearest to box[7]  
box[6] is nearest to box[12]  
box[6] is nearest to box[13]  
Total number of nearest box for [6] is 3  

box[7] is nearest to box[3]  
box[7] is nearest to box[6]  
box[7] is nearest to box[9]  
box[7] is nearest to box[15]  
Total number of nearest box for [7] is 4  

box[8] is nearest to box[1]  
box[8] is nearest to box[4]  
box[8] is nearest to box[14]  
box[8] is nearest to box[16]  
Total number of nearest box for [8] is 4  

box[9] is nearest to box[7]  
box[9] is nearest to box[10]  
box[9] is nearest to box[15]  
box[9] is nearest to box[16]  
Total number of nearest box for [9] is 4  

box[10] is nearest to box[4]  
box[10] is nearest to box[9]  
Total number of nearest box for [10] is 2  

box[11] is nearest to box[2]  
box[11] is nearest to box[5]  
box[11] is nearest to box[12]  
Total number of nearest box for [11] is 3  

box[12] is nearest to box[6]  
box[12] is nearest to box[11]  
box[12] is nearest to box[13]  
Total number of nearest box for [12] is 3  

box[13] is nearest to box[3]  
box[13] is nearest to box[5]  
box[13] is nearest to box[6]  
box[13] is nearest to box[12]  
Total number of nearest box for [13] is 4  

box[14] is nearest to box[1]  
box[14] is nearest to box[3]  
box[14] is nearest to box[8]  
box[14] is nearest to box[15]  
Total number of nearest box for [14] is 4  

box[15] is nearest to box[3]  
box[15] is nearest to box[7]  
box[15] is nearest to box[9]  
box[15] is nearest to box[14]  
box[15] is nearest to box[16]  
Total number of nearest box for [15] is 5  

box[16] is nearest to box[4]  
box[16] is nearest to box[8]  
box[16] is nearest to box[9]  
box[16] is nearest to box[15]  
Total number of nearest box for [16] is 4
```

Although it can identify the nearest boxes and count the number of neighbors but I could not figure out how can I group the similar boxes (as stated above) and find the sum.

And I am stuck here. Can anyone help me?

**Updated Code Snippet**

```
vector<CheckRect> rects;

unsigned isNearest(unsigned b, vector<unsigned>& neighbours) {

  unsigned nearBox_count = 0;

  for (unsigned x = 0; x < rects.size(); ++x) {
    if (rects[b].isAdjacent(rects[x])) {
      if (x==b) continue; //this is our box , so do not count it.
      nearBox_count++;
      printf("box[%d] is nearest to box[%d]  \n", (b+1), (x+1));
      neighbours.push_back(x);
    }
  }

  printf("Total number of nearest box for [%d] is %d  \n",
        (b+1), nearBox_count );
  printf("\n");

  return nearBox_count;
}

int main(){

cin>>N;

for(int b=0; b<N; b++){

  ifstream inputFile1("RectCoordinates.txt"); //input from the file previously generated
  int rect_number;
  double xa0,ya0,xa1,ya1;
  int neighbours;
  isNearest( b, &neighbours);// This is the line that causing my ERROR


  }
 vector<unsigned> nearBox_count(rects.size());
  vector< vector<unsigned> > neighbours(rects.size());
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < rects.size(); ++i) {
    nearBox_count[i] = isNearest(i, neighbours[i]);
  }

  // Calculate the sums of neighbouring boxes
  vector<unsigned> neighCount(rects.size(), 0);
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++) {
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < neighbours[i].size(); j++) {
      neighCount[i] += nearBox_count[neighbours[i][j]];
    }
  }

  // Calculate your result
  map<unsigned,unsigned> finalCount;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++)
  {
    if (finalCount.count(nearBox_count[i]) == 0)
      finalCount[nearBox_count[i]] = neighCount[i];
    else
      finalCount[nearBox_count[i]] += neighCount[i];
  }

  // Print the result
  for (map<unsigned,unsigned>::iterator it = finalCount.begin();
        it != finalCount.end(); ++it) {
    printf("Sum neighbours for the neighbours of similar boxes with %d "
           "neighbours is %d\n", it->first, it->second);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Gives me the error-

```
ss.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ss.cpp:102:29: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::vector<unsigned int>&’ from expression of type ‘unsigned int’
ss.cpp:22:10: error: in passing argument 2 of ‘unsigned int isNearest(unsigned int, std::vector<unsigned int>&)’
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: @haccks Yes, I am a student of physics. Working on this type of problem for a while. This is a part of the problem I am stuck with. :(

Comment: I have seen many of your **Box** questions, that's why I asked you.

Comment: @haccks You are right. I wish this might be the last question regarding the boxes. But it all depends on the results actually.

Comment: You want to fix the error? Simply remove the `&` from the line that causes it. The argument type is __reference__ not a __pointer__. By the way this is a common mistake for `C++` programmers who used to write in `C`.

Comment: @RondogiannisAristophanes That is not actually the error.  The error is that aries0152 is trying to pass an integer instead of a vector of integers to the function `isNearest`.  The `&` should also be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as attempt to calculate your value, I have made a few minor changes to your code.

Since all your list indices are never negative and it is likely you will have a very large number of rectangles in the future, I would suggest making all your `int`s into `unsigned`.  This has the added advantage of suppressing certain compiler warnings about comparing signed and unsigned integers in the code bellow.

The second change I suggest you make is to declare `rects` only once instead of every time you iterate through `isNearest`.  In the code bellow, I have achieved this by making `rects` a global variable and creating a separate function to initialise it.  By making `rects` a global variable, you can now replace all your `16`s with `rects.size()` (reduce any chance of forgetting to change one `16` when you add in your full dataset).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Rect {
public:
  double x1, x2, y1, y2; // coordinates

  Rect(double X1, double Y1, double X2, double Y2) {
    if (X1 < X2) {
      x1 = X1; x2 = X2;
    } else {
      x2 = X1; x1 = X2;
    }
    if (Y1 < Y2) {
      y1 = Y1; y2 = Y2;
    } else {
      y2 = Y1; y1 = Y2;
    }
}

bool isAdjacent(Rect rect) {
    if (x1 == rect.x1 || x1 == rect.x2 ||
        x2 == rect.x1 || x2 == rect.x2) {
      // use only < when comparing y1 and rect.y2 avoids sharing only a corner
      if (y1 >= rect.y1 && y1 < rect.y2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (y2 > rect.y1 && y2 <= rect.y2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect.y1 >= y1 && rect.y1 < y2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect.y2 > y1 && rect.y2 <= y2) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    if (y1 == rect.y1 || y1 == rect.y2 ||
        y2 == rect.y1 || y2 == rect.y2) {
      if (x1 >= rect.x1 && x1 < rect.x2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (x2 > rect.x1 && x2 <= rect.x2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect.x1 >= x1 && rect.x1 < x2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect.x2 > x1 && rect.x2 <= x2) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
};

vector<Rect> rects;

unsigned isNearest(unsigned b, vector<unsigned>& neighbours) {

  unsigned nearBox_count = 0;

  for (unsigned x = 0; x < rects.size(); ++x) {
    if (rects[b].isAdjacent(rects[x])) {
      if (x==b) continue; //this is our box , so do not count it.
      nearBox_count++;
      printf("box[%d] is nearest to box[%d]  \n", (b+1), (x+1));
      neighbours.push_back(x);
    }
  }

  printf("Total number of nearest box for [%d] is %d  \n",
        (b+1), nearBox_count );
  printf("\n");

  return nearBox_count;
}

void initRects(void) {

                //Rect(  x1 ,  y1  ,   x2  ,  y2   ) 
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.0000,0.0000, 0.8147,0.1355));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.8147,0.0000, 1.0000,0.1355));

  rects.push_back(Rect(0.8147,0.1355, 0.9058,0.8350));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.0000,0.1355, 0.1270,0.9689));

  rects.push_back(Rect(0.9058,0.1355, 0.9134,0.2210));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.9058,0.8350, 1.0000,1.0000));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.8147,0.8350, 0.9058,1.0000));


  rects.push_back(Rect(0.1270,0.1355, 0.6324,0.3082));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.1270,0.9689, 0.8147,1.0000));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.0000,0.9689, 0.1270,1.0000));

  rects.push_back(Rect(0.9134,0.1355, 1.0000,0.2210));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.9134,0.2210, 1.0000,0.8350));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.9058,0.2210, 0.9134,0.8350));


  rects.push_back(Rect(0.6324,0.1355, 0.8147,0.3082));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.6324,0.3082, 0.8147,0.9689));
  rects.push_back(Rect(0.1270,0.3082, 0.6324,0.9689));
}

void readRects(const string& filename) {

  ifstream fpInput(filename.c_str());
  double dTemp[4];

  while (true) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 4; i++) fpInput >> dTemp[i];
    if (!fpInput.good()) break;
    rects.push_back(Rect(dTemp[0], dTemp[1], dTemp[2], dTemp[3]));
  }

  fpInput.close();
}

int main() {

  // Initialize the vector rects
  //initRects();
  readRects("RectCoordinates.txt");

  vector<unsigned> nearBox_count(rects.size());
  vector< vector<unsigned> > neighbours(rects.size());
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < rects.size(); ++i) {
    nearBox_count[i] = isNearest(i, neighbours[i]);
  }

  // Calculate the sums of neighbouring boxes
  vector<unsigned> neighCount(rects.size(), 0);
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++) {
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < neighbours[i].size(); j++) {
      neighCount[i] += nearBox_count[neighbours[i][j]];
    }
  }

  // Calculate your result
  map<unsigned,unsigned> finalCount;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++)
  {
    if (finalCount.count(nearBox_count[i]) == 0) {
      finalCount[nearBox_count[i]] = neighCount[i];
    } else {
      finalCount[nearBox_count[i]] += neighCount[i];
    }
  }

  // Print the result
  for (map<unsigned,unsigned>::iterator it = finalCount.begin();
        it != finalCount.end(); ++it) {
    printf("Sum neighbours for the neighbours of similar boxes with %d "
           "neighbours is %d\n", it->first, it->second);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Update:** The above code can now be used by either specifying the `Rect`s inside the source file or loaded from an external file.  In the modified example above, the input file is `RectCoordinates.txt`:

```
0.0000  0.0000  0.8147  0.1355
0.8147  0.0000  1.0000  0.1355

0.8147  0.1355  0.9058  0.8350
0.0000  0.1355  0.1270  0.9689

0.9058  0.1355  0.9134  0.2210
0.9058  0.8350  1.0000  1.0000
0.8147  0.8350  0.9058  1.0000


0.1270  0.1355  0.6324  0.3082
0.1270  0.9689  0.8147  1.0000
0.0000  0.9689  0.1270  1.0000

0.9134  0.1355  1.0000  0.2210
0.9134  0.2210  1.0000  0.8350
0.9058  0.2210  0.9134  0.8350


0.6324  0.1355  0.8147  0.3082
0.6324  0.3082  0.8147  0.9689
0.1270  0.3082  0.6324  0.9689
```

The above outputs the results:

```
Sum neighbours for the neighbours of similar boxes with 2 neighbours is 8
Sum neighbours for the neighbours of similar boxes with 3 neighbours is 32
Sum neighbours for the neighbours of similar boxes with 4 neighbours is 165
Sum neighbours for the neighbours of similar boxes with 5 neighbours is 22
Sum neighbours for the neighbours of similar boxes with 6 neighbours is 25
```

Comment: Nice ! I was thinking of using a text file and get the input from that for the values of rects. Till now it seems working like I want. Let me check with other values.

Comment: Your code gives me the correct result. But I am facing problem while get the inputs of rects from a text file. It is showing the error- _" invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::vector<unsigned int>&’ from expression of type ‘unsigned int’"_. How can I fix it? I have **updated** my code. Please check.

Comment: @aries0152 I have updated my post.  The code now reads in a file containing the data points.  The error was because you where trying to pass an `int` instead of a `vector<unsigned int>` to the updated function `isNearest`.  `isNearest` returns the number of neighbours and stores the actual neighbours in the variable `neighbours`.

Answer (score 3):

Rather then trying to maintain relationship between rectangles in some data structures, it might be a better idea to make rectangle object itself smart and aware of number of it neighbors and who they are.

For example (incomplete proptotype to illustrate idea):

```
class Rect {
public:
//methods
Rect(double X1, double Y1, double X2, double Y2);

//const access
double getX1() const;
double getX2() const;
double getY1() const;
double getY2() const;

int numNeighbors() const { return neighbors.size();}
int sumOfNeighbors() const { int res(0); for(size_t i=0;i< neighbors.size();++i) res += neighbors[i]->numNeighbors(); return res;}
std::vector<Rect*> getNeighbors() {return neighbors};

void addNeighbor(Rect* newNeighbor) {neighbors.push_back(newNeighbor);}

//data
private:

double x1, x2, y1, y2; // coordinates
std::vector<Rect*> neighbors;
};
```

With such rect class you can add neighbors to each rectangle, retrieve its own all neighbors of each rect, and all of their neighbors - all relationships are maintained within rect itself rather then some external object, code of main program should be very minimal.

Once you populate rects, you can simply iterate though them, pick ones having  required number of neighbors, and do whatever operation on them.

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you want to drastically simplify all of this you can use Mr. Kobelevskiy's recommendation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class Rect {
public:
double x1, x2, y1, y2; // coordinates

//methods
Rect(double X1, double Y1, double X2, double Y2) {
  if (X1 < X2) {
    x1 = X1; x2 = X2;
  } else {
    x2 = X1; x1 = X2;
  }
  if (Y1 < Y2) {
    y1 = Y1; y2 = Y2;
  } else {
    y2 = Y1; y1 = Y2;
  }
}

~Rect()
{
};

int numNeighbors() const { return neighbors.size();}
int sumOfNeighbors() const { int res(0); for(size_t i=0;i< neighbors.size();++i) res += neighbors[i]->numNeighbors(); return res;}
std::vector<Rect*> getNeighbors() {return neighbors;};

void addNeighbor(Rect* newNeighbor) {neighbors.push_back(newNeighbor);}

//data
std::vector<Rect*> neighbors;

bool isAdjacent(Rect* rect) {
    if (x1 == rect->x1 || x1 == rect->x2 ||
        x2 == rect->x1 || x2 == rect->x2) {
      // use only < when comparing y1 and rect->y2 avoids sharing only a corner
      if (y1 >= rect->y1 && y1 < rect->y2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (y2 > rect->y1 && y2 <= rect->y2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect->y1 >= y1 && rect->y1 < y2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect->y2 > y1 && rect->y2 <= y2) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    if (y1 == rect->y1 || y1 == rect->y2 ||
        y2 == rect->y1 || y2 == rect->y2) {
      if (x1 >= rect->x1 && x1 < rect->x2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (x2 > rect->x1 && x2 <= rect->x2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect->x1 >= x1 && rect->x1 < x2) {
        return true;
      }
      if (rect->x2 > x1 && rect->x2 <= x2) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

};

vector<Rect*> rects;

void CalculateAdjacentsForRect(unsigned int rects_element){

    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < rects.size(); x++) {
        if (rects[rects_element]->isAdjacent(rects[x])) {
            if (x==rects_element) {
                continue; //this is our box , so do not count it.
            }
            rects[rects_element]->addNeighbor(rects[x]);
        }
    }
}

const int MAX_ADJACENT_RECTS = 10;

int main() {

                    //Rect(  x1 ,  y1  ,   x2  ,  y2   )
    rects.push_back(&Rect(0.0000,0.0000, 0.8147,0.1355));
    rects.push_back(&Rect(0.8147,0.0000, 1.0000,0.1355));

    rects.push_back(&Rect(0.8147,0.1355, 0.9058,0.8350));
    rects.push_back(&Rect(0.0000,0.1355, 0.1270,0.9689));

    rects.push_back(&Rect(0.9058,0.1355, 0.9134,0.2210));
    rects.push_back(&Rect(0.9058,0.8350, 1.0000,1.0000));
    rects.push_back(&Rect(0.8147,0.8350, 0.9058,1.0000));


    rects.push_back(&Rect(0.1270,0.1355, 0.6324,0.3082));
    rects.push_back(&Rect(0.1270,0.9689, 0.8147,1.0000));
    rects.push_back(&Rect(0.0000,0.9689, 0.1270,1.0000));

    rects.push_back(&Rect(0.9134,0.1355, 1.0000,0.2210));
    rects.push_back(&Rect(0.9134,0.2210, 1.0000,0.8350));
    rects.push_back(&Rect(0.9058,0.2210, 0.9134,0.8350));


    rects.push_back(&Rect(0.6324,0.1355, 0.8147,0.3082));
    rects.push_back(&Rect(0.6324,0.3082, 0.8147,0.9689));
    rects.push_back(&Rect(0.1270,0.3082, 0.6324,0.9689));

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++)
    {
        CalculateAdjacentsForRect(i);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "\nRect" << i << " has a neighbor sum of " << rects[i]->sumOfNeighbors();
    }

    cout << "\n";

    for (int ix = 0; ix < MAX_ADJACENT_RECTS; ix++)
    {
        int num_rects_with_this_num_of_adjacents = 0;
        int num_adjacents_total_for_similar_rects = 0;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++) {
            if ( rects[i]->numNeighbors() == ix ) {
               num_rects_with_this_num_of_adjacents++;
               num_adjacents_total_for_similar_rects += rects[i]->sumOfNeighbors();
            }
        }
        cout << "\nThere are " << num_rects_with_this_num_of_adjacents << " rects with " << ix << " adjacent rects. They have a cum neighbor sum of " << num_adjacents_total_for_similar_rects;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have learned a new way to solve this problem. Voted up. :)

Comment: @aries0152 See this version. Mr. Kobelevskiy's framework drastically simplifies it all. I guess it is better to use pointers for these kinds of things. It certainly helps when you are trying to reference through vectors and compare elements. I ran into a lot of problems with my non-pointer version that went away with this version.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose you could use vectors, but this way can take a lot of memory space.
Say, make vector 4neighbours - at first sight, I'd say each box as at least 4 neighbours (You would have, however to do this for every possible number of neighbours - Hopefully, it can be calculated, and it won't be super-big).  Then, when checking the number of neighbours of each rectangle use pushback on the corresponding vector.

```
printf("Total number of nearest box for [%d] is %d  \n",(b+1),nearBox_count );
if(nearBox_count == 4)
 4neighbours.pushback(rects[b]);
else if (nearBox_count == 5)
 5neighbours.pushback(rects[b]);
else if -etc-
```

Then, go through the vector and for each member of the vector, check the neighbours, and for each neighbour calculate the neighbours and sum it up (You'd be nesting two loops - A loop inside a loop)

Example: **Not coded**

```
int TotalNeighbours = 0;
while(go through all the boxes in the vector)
{
    while(go through all the neighbours of each box)
    {
     TotalNeighbours++;
    }
}
```

I believe something like this might work, with, however the limitations mentioned above.
Depending on the maximum number of neighbours:

- A lot of memory usage;
- A lot of written code (lots of if statements);

*Edit: One box can have 0 neighbours, an the rest has at least 1 neighbour, not 4.*

Comment: I have already thought of that. But in this way I have to use about 40-50 if statements.

Comment: @aries0152 Yes, an if statement per each possible number of neighbours, if I'm not mistaken. It really is a last-resort sort of thing. If no better/understandable solution shows up and you have time, lots of code can do the trick. However, in this case, I believe some better way will show up.

Comment: @Sampaio Although not in the example given above, edge boxes could have 1 neighbour and if there was only one box 0 neighbours.

Comment: @ilent2 You are correct, I (wrongly) assumed boxes would get smaller with number (box(x) < box(x+1)), but, looking at the example given, that is clearly not true. Valuable lesson: don't jump to conclusions.